# Certicate verification with OpenSSL commandline

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, openssl

I am trying to verify a random certificate with OpenSSL in Windows. I've installed `Win32 OpenSSL`, but how do I verify a random certificate with the OpenSSL commandline? I know there are other ways, but I want to use the OpenSSL commandline :)

Thanks for you help!

EDIT:
When I use `openssl verify cacert.pem` it gives me this error:
[image]

New error:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

openssl verify -CAfile ca-bundle.crt certificate.crt

or

openssl verify -CApath cadirectory certificate.crt

To verify a certificate, you need the chain, going back to a Root Certificate Authority, of the certificate authorities that signed it.  If it is a server certificate on the public internet, that is likely (but not necessarily) one of the hundredish Root CAs that are trusted by the browsers.  Those Root CA's public keys are shipped with every browser (in the equivalent of the ca directory in the second openssl command).  Ultimately, each user of root certificates needs to decide what authorities they will trust - for browsers, that decision is made by the browser manufacturers and is a Big Deal (tm).  You can find the root CAs each trusts - and use that in your root ca directory - if you want, or choose your own.

Comment: I think the key here is that you can't ABSOLUTELY verify a certificate - you can only verify it against something.  You decide what the something is - a homegrown certificate authority?  The consensus root CAs that Google and Microsoft and Mozilla trust?  That list minus some in countries you don't approve of?  It is up to you...

Comment: Could you please provide an example? The CAfile, do I have to change that, the ca-bundle.crt and certificate.crt? Where do I find these information?

Comment: Basically, each Certificate Authority (CA) has a public key (which they share) and a private key (which they do not).  These CAs can be public ones (Thawte, Comodo, to name just a few) or private ones (set up by an individual or a company for internal use). The consumers of the certificates decide which CAs they will trust - in the case of the public web, that choosing is done by the browser manufacturers - they ship a list of CA public keys with their browsers. You could use those lists, if you choose to do so.  Or you could make your own list. Or you could only trust your own Root CA.

Comment: Of course, if you only trust your own Root CA (or if you make your own list of public CAs), you will not be able to verify as valid certificates not part of your list. You can find extracted Root CA lists from browsers by googling, or look at https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA:IncludedCAs - the PEMs mentioned are all the public keys.  If you extract all those public keys to a directory and use CApath as above, you will trust the same ones as Mozilla. Note it isn't a static list - the manufacturers trust additional CAs (and occasionally untrust CAs) from time to time.

Comment: certificate.crt is a file that contains the certificate - if you want to download that from an external website, you can use : openssl s_client -connect {HOSTNAME}:{PORT} -showcerts

Comment: have tried to verify a certificate but I get an error even though I've the certificate. Have edited the OP

Comment: cat the cacert.pem file (by name, this appears to be the CA certificate, not the certificate you want to verify).  PEM files should start with -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and end with -----END CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: I don't get it... :(

Comment: You should have at least one file - the certificate file you want to verify. If it is in PEM format, you should see the -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- at the beginning if you open it in a text editor (cat is a unix command to list the contents of the file).  Make sure that file is in the working directory and use openssl verify certificate.file.name.here.  Now, that won't work, per se, as you won't have any root certs to verify against. Put those root certs in a directory and use the -CApath parameter to refer to that directory

Comment: You always need two things - a certificate to verify and a collection of at least one CA public certificates.  In order for it to work, your collection needs to contain the CA public certificate for the CA that signed the certificate you are trying to verify.

Comment: How do I change the working directory to my desktop? The .pem file is there, but I don't have the the .crt file. As I understand from what you're writing then no

Comment: Run the openssl command from a command prompt in your desktop directory.  We're rapidly getting off topic here, however - this isn't intended to be OS support :)

Comment: Sorry, I did that and now I get another error. have changed the OP

Comment: That means you don't have the appropriate root CA available.  As I said, you need to specify the --CAPath directory with appropriate certs in it

Answer (score 1):

The first error was due to your trying to 'read' (and verify) a non-existent file.

The second would *seem* to not be an error, but a 'proper' failure to verify.

What the message actually says it that it cannot find the CA that issued the cert you are testing, and so cannot validate the chain (which would generally be, at minimum issuing CA > your cert).

The `SSLeay demo server` line in your second output would tend to indicate one reason for this is that indeed, you just generated a new CA.

It also looks like you are trying to validate your own CA cert, which is a little redundant - but if you really want to do that, you should run:

```
openssl verify -CAfile cacert.pem cacert.pem
```

A more useful/practical example would be validating a (hopefully) known-good cert. Not sure if you can pipe on Windows, but on Linux, you could do:

```
openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 </dev/null | openssl verify
```

If you want to see the cert, you can run:

```
openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 </dev/null | openssl x509 -text
```

I think you might want to spend a bit of time reading up on how PKI works: generally, a PKI is built when a 'trusted' entity (a Certificate Authority) issues a certificate for another entity - it basically vouches for that other entity (which can be an organisation, a server, a user, etc) being who it claims to be.

So validating/verifying a cert involves the following (grossly simplified explanation coming up):

- from your end-user cert (i.e. the cert used on the domain you are checking - user here is whatever is making use of the cert, not necessarily a human), the Issuer is checked, and the Issuer's public key is also extract (for comparison against known keys for that issuer).
- you could then check first that your end-user cert is properly signed (i.e. the signature contained in the cert is signed by the private key linked to the Issuer's public key, which is included in the cert)
- you could then validate the Issuer's cert, either by checking a list of known-good certs (which is what the OS cert store does), or by repeating the previous two steps if the Issuer has been issued its cert by some other entity.

At some point, you end up at a self-signed cert belonging to an entity such as Verisign/LetsEncrypt/YourCAHere, which is the root of the chain of trust the PKI reflects.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of minutes ago [another related post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138376/verifying-a-certificate-with-the-openssl-commandline-tool) appeared on this site. The author [linked this page](https://kb.wisc.edu/middleware/page.php?id=4543) which makes me believe that you should check

```
openssl verify
```

Comment: I've seen that, but how should I know what -CAfile, cacert.pem & server.crt are? I mean where can I find the names?

Comment: As the answer to the post says: server.crt is the certificate you want to verify and cacert.pem is the root CA certificate that has issued the certificate.

Comment: Ok, I want to try with this certificate: ComSignCA.crt and the root is ComSign when I write this information I it says that it cannot open the input file ComSign.pem. No such file